# Prevent system from taking a "use on resume" snapshot of app

Tags: ios, screen-capture

I have some sensitive data displayed to my user within the app, and when the user clicks the home button and comes back into the app, Apple has a snapshot functionality that displays a picture of the last screen on the device before the home button was pressed.

Is there any way to disable this effect entirely? I have seen ways here to display an image upon background activation that pushes on top of the view and is displayed first in place of the snapshot when the user returns to the app, but I would like this feature to go away entirely and not have to save any snapshots or any other screen capture when the user goes into the app again. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Note that I am not talking about taking a screenshot with home button + sleep button press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `applicationWillResignActive:` method of your app delegate, you can make a UIImageView of something inconspicuous pop-up. For example, let's say your application holds a user's passwords. Someone is walking behind the user and the user presses the home button. This calls the `applicationWillResignActive:` method, which puts up perhaps a map view, so when the walker is gone and the user reopens the application, it opens directly to a map view instead of to a brief snapshot of the users passwords. This is how you might implement it:

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picOfMap.png"]];
    image.frame = self.view.frame;
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: image];
}
```

And here's a description of when `applicationWillResignActive:` is called:

> This method is called to let your application know that it is about to move from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state. An application in the inactive state continues to run but does not dispatch incoming events to responders. ([UIApplicationDelegate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html))

There may be some bugs in the code because I'm not familiar with working in the App Delegate, but that's the gist of what you should do.

Comment: But i dont want that view to come up again when the user comes back into the app. I want the user to click the home button and when they come back in, no snapshot at all is displayed, whether it be the view the user was looking at before the home button press (snapshot) or even anything i might force onto the screen just before the home press (your solution above). I want NO image/view to be there whether it be inconspicuous or not

Comment: @JohnBaum - When the application reopens after being closed by the user, the snapshot will be of an "inconspicuous" image rather than the sensitive data that would have been shown. You can put code to remove the image in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, so the user is brought back to their original screen. Basically, all my code does is replaces the old snapshot of sensitive data, with a bland image that means nothing; it doesn't affect anything else whatsoever.

Comment: @JohnBaum what do you want to show?  it seems like from that comment, you would like a blank screen.

Comment: I really ideally wanted to override Apple and not have any screen displayed at all. Sort of mute this "feature" and prevent it from ever existing. I dont want a blank screen to be displayed as that takes away from the user experience if they see a random image when they come back in

Comment: @JohnBaum - As iOS is a mobile platform **created by Apple**, I doubt that you can "override" them (without jailbreaking the device of course).

Comment: So you don't want to show a lock screen, you don't want to show a blank screen, what do you want to appear? "nothing" doesn't make sense to me - there has to be something drawn on the screen!

Comment: The above code doesnt work for me when ive tried to integrate it. It doesnt seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Technical Q&A by Apple on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html

In short, code snippets in Swift are following:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let someVCToShowInAppSwitcher = ...
    window?.rootViewController?.present(someVCToShowInAppSwitcher, animated: false)
}
```

and

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Make sure that we'll dismiss an expected VC, e.g.:
    if window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.view.accessibilityIdentifier == "someVCToShowInAppSwitcher" {
        window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(sender: self)
    }
}
```