# Five Finger Pinch to Close (Pinch to Home) Black Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, gesture

What is my app supposed to do (or might it currently be doing incorrectly) to support correct visuals when a five finger pinch to close gesture is executed by the user?

When the five finger pinch to close app gesture is performed on my iPad app, the image of my app UI that is used for the shrinking transition is a black screen. There is one exception; when my app is first launched the gesture uses the correct snapshot of my app UI as long as I do not navigate away from the initial screen.

As a test, I added the code below to see if I could get a red screen in all cases. The result was a red screen in the case that used to show my app UI, and still get a black screen in the failure case.

> ```
> - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
> {
>     UIView *aView = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject;
>     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:aView.bounds];
>     imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
>     [aView addSubview:imageView];
> }
> ```

I realize this question is vague, but what I am hoping for is insight into where iOS is getting the screen it uses during the pinch to close gesture. Based on the above code there is more to it than applicationWillResignActive.

I am building with Xcode 5.1.1, iOS 7.0 deployment target, problem occurs running on iOS7 and iOS8 (all versions up to and including public release of 8.1).

**Edit**

If I continue the shrink gesture by pinching further and further, when the thumbnail image of my app gets to about 25% of the screen size, the empty black image snaps to a correct image of my app UI. At that point I can reverse the gesture (spread my fingers apart) and the correct image grows all the way to full screen. During this process, the image is crisp and not scaled.

If I have focus in a text field and tap and hold with one finger to bring up the magnification loupe, then drop my other four fingers and start the shrink, the black screen shows my UI in a circle where the loupe was (rest is black).

As I mentioned in the comments below, a double tap on the home button always yields a correct snapshot for fast app switching.

My app does not have any background threads running and is not requesting specific permissions to run long running tasks in the background.

Comment: Not sure either, all of mine seem to work as expected and none of them do anything special around it, or even with the [resume snapshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607153/prevent-system-from-taking-a-use-on-resume-snapshot-of-app)

Comment: As an experiment, in applicationWillResignActive, I added a fullscreen view with a red backgroundColor to my app's keyWindow. Now the screen goes red when the five finger pinch gesture is executed right after app launch but still goes black once the main screen is left.

Comment: A colleague suggested that maybe the keyWindow view hierarchy was getting broken somewhere in my app so the OS did not have access to all the views for snapshot rendering. Good thought. In applicationWillResignActive I logged all views and their subviews from the application keyWindow on down. The results were the same in the success case and the failure case. So the view hierarchy seems fine.

Comment: I also removed the Reveal framework I use for debugging. Same results with Reveal out of my project.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the app image is always correct during fast app switching (double press home)

Answer (score 0):

Any change your app uses -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:YES anywhere?  I'm seeing the same issue when using that API.  It seems like there are quite a few GPU bugs related to setting afterScreenUpdates to YES.

Changing my app to use renderInContext (cpu instead of gpu) fixed the problem, but doing that introduces other issues, so it's a toss up.

Comment: Yes, I am using drawViewHeirarchyInRect in some places because renderInContext does not always work. So I guess the ugly pinch to close thumbnail is better than a black rectangle all the time in my app.